# Unexpected Error while deleting file on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7

I get an unexpected error while deleting file on Windows 7 x64:

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers listed here:
[Error 0x80070570: How to delete corrupted and unreadable file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/63641/error-0x80070570-how-to-delete-corrupted-and-unreadable-file)